# running command in script on a time condition

Tags: shell

I want to run certain commands in a script. 
Something like:

```
if(today is monday){
  do something;
}
```

Is there a way to do this in a shell script?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a POSIX compliant shell:

```
if [ "$(date +%A)" = "Monday" ]; then
    echo "something"
fi
```

The *+%A* will return the full name of the current day. See

```
date --help
```

for more format options.

Comment: This should work in any POSIX shell, although `$( ... )` is preferred to backquotes.

Comment: Be aware that the `%a` and `%A` formats depend on the language. Prepend `LC_ALL=C ` or use `%u` or `%w` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use the date command to get the numerical representation of the week 
# (or whatever format you are looking for)
check=$(date +%u)

if [ "$check" == 1 ]; then
    # Monday
    # Do something
elif [ "$check" == 2 ]; then
    # Monday
    # Do something
...
elif [ "$check" == 7 ]; then
    # Sunday
    # Do something
fi
```

*edit- added bin/bash for completeness*

Comment: does this work on all platforms? Date is a linux command, what about windows. My script might be run on both windows and linux

Comment: *nix environments only.  Can you guaranty another language on the boxes, say php or ruby?

Comment: If you have `bash` installed under Windows, I suspect `date` can be installed as well. If it needs to run under both operating systems, you're going to be installing software somewhere; there is no shell that ships with both.

Answer (score -1):

If using Windows you can use this to schedule processes for certain dates/times:

```
schtasks
```

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true

If you just want to check the day, first 3 characters of `%DATE%` are day of the week